# Access word from file using bash script

Tags: bash

I have following service file.

```
[Unit]
Description=Airflow celery worker daemon
After=network.target

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/airflow
User=airflow
Group=airflow
Type=simple
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10s
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/airflow worker -q Test
```

I want to extract "Test" form file which always will be in after `ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/airflow worker -q`. It can be anything, not just "Test".

I have following code:

```
file="file path"
while IFS= read line
do
        # display $line or do somthing with $line
        echo "$line"
        if [ "$line" = *"ExecStart"* ]; then
                echo "It's there!"
        fi


done <"$file"
```

However, I am not able to `echo It's there`. It will be great help, if any one can guide it to extract "Test" in variable so I can dump in psql using following command.

```
sql -U postgres -d database_name -c "SELECT c_defaults  FROM user_info WHERE c_uid = 'Test'"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind using `awk` instead of pure Bash,
this can be very easy:

```
awk '/^ExecStart=/ { print $NF; exit }' /path/to/input
```

You can save this in a variable by wrapping in `$(...)`:

```
word=$(awk '/^ExecStart=/ { print $NF; exit }' /path/to/input)
```

And then you can embed it in the SQL command:

```
sql -U postgres -d database_name -c "SELECT c_defaults  FROM user_info WHERE c_uid = '$word'"
```

Or a pure Bash solution:

```
read_word() {
     while read line; do
         [[ "$line" == ExecStart=* ]] || continue
         echo ${line//* }
         return
     done < /path/to/input
}

word=$(read_word)
```